# pySerial serial.open() works in interactive shell but raises exception as a script

Tags: python, pyserial

EDIT: It seems like the issue might have to do with Python 3. I tried executing the script in a Anaconda Environment of Python 2.7.15 and was able to get it to work. Thinking it might be just Anaconda, I tried running it in a Anaconda Environment of Python 3.6.5 and ran into the same error. To remove the variable of Anaconda, I tried running Python 2.7.15 from a fresh install without Anaconda and was again able to get the script running properly. Note that my original problem came up when running through a non-Anaconda Python3 environment. I do not think this really answers the question but is somewhat of a solution for anyone running into the same issue.

Windows 10. Python 3.6.5

I am trying to establish/open a connection with a connected COM port through pyserial. I am able to do this just fine through a Python shell started in cmd, but receive an exception when running it through a script. The exception chain is this:

```
File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 62, in open
raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM8': OSError(22, 'Element not found.', None, 1168)
```

The script is this:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
import time
import sys

SERIAL_CONNECTION_ATTEMPTS = 3

ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
bluetoothPorts = []

for p in ports:
    if 'Bluetooth' in p.description:
        bluetoothPorts.append(p)
        print("Found: ", p)

selectedPort = bluetoothPorts[0]
print("selected port: ", selectedPort.device)

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.timeout = 120
ser.port = selectedPort.device

for i in range(0, SERIAL_CONNECTION_ATTEMPTS):
    try:
        ser.open()
        time.sleep(5)
        if ser.is_open():
            break
    except:
        print(sys.exc_info())
        if i == SERIAL_CONNECTION_ATTEMPTS-1:
            print("Failed to connect. Will stop trying now.")
            exit()
        print("Failed to connect. Retrying...")    
        ser.close()
        time.sleep(5)

print(ser.read(32))        
print("Closing out now..")
ser.close()
```

Successful connections using the interactive shell follow the script exactly, excluding the use of the try-except block.

One thing I have noticed is that the target device seems to recognize a connection attempt for a very brief moment. I am able to make this guess because the target device has an LED to indicate an established serial connection. When the script runs to the `ser.open()`, this LED flashes for a moment before quickly turning off. On the other hand, when `ser.open()` is attempted in the interactive shell, the shell blocks until the connection is made and the LED stays lit.

Please let me know if any additional information would help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your main problem, but I would like to point out that `if i is SERIAL_CONNECTION_ATTEMPTS-1:` is horribly broken.  `is` tests *object identity*, NOT *value equality*; it would be quite possible for the numeric values on both sides to be equal, yet be represented by distinct integer objects, and therefore for the test to fail.  This isn't likely with your current maximum of 3 attempts, but if that was raised to at least 257, failure would be *guaranteed* (assuming standard Python build settings).

Comment: @jasonharper Hi thanks a lot for pointing that out! When I first wrote the script I did `if i == SERIAL_CONNECTION_ATTEMPTS-1` as I am used to in my daily programming. I think some time that day I read some example code that used `if x is y` and I thought it'd visually look cool. So I put it in there without actually reading up on the proper use case. I have reverted it now and will edit the OP as well. Thanks again for educating me :)

Answer (score 0):

well you know Bluetooth, it doesn't work from the first attempt, just give it a try, one and two and three ...

```
def getSerialOrNone(port, conn_att):
connec_attempts = 0
ser = None
while ser is None:
    try:
        connec_attempts+=1
        print('connect attempts to %s num %d' % (port , (connec_attempts)))
        ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600,timeout=1.5, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, 
                                stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)
        if connec_attempts == conn_att:
                print('Serial connection error',
                                       'Failed to commect to port  ', self.port  )        
                return None
#time.sleep(2)
    except Exception as e:
            print('Serial connection error',
                                   'Error sending message "%s" to controller:\n%s' %
                               (port, e))     
return ser
```